# How to list questions and answers within two separate arrays and return them alternating in two text view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have these arrays of questions and answers:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
CharSequence[] questionsCorrect = b.getCharSequenceArray("questionsCorrect");
CharSequence[] answersCorrect = b.getCharSequenceArray("answersCorrect");
```

In the next activity, how can I separate each question from each answer and return them in 2 textViews?

Comment: Are Questions and answers associated to each other based on the index?
I mean `questionsCorrect[0]` has answer at `answersCorrect[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model to represent each question and answer separately.

```
public class QAnsModel implements Serializable
{
    private String question, answer;

    public QAnsModel(String question, String answer)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.asnwer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion()
    {
        return question;
    }

    public String getAnswer()
    {
        return answer;
    }
}
```

In your activity,

```
// Your mentioned code
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
CharSequence[] questionsCorrect = b.getCharSequenceArray("questionsCorrect");
CharSequence[] answersCorrect = b.getCharSequenceArray("answersCorrect");

// Create a list of questions and answers. Make sure both arrays have same length
QAnsModel model;
ArrayList<QAnsModel> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < questionsCorrect.length; i++)
{
    model = new QAnsModel(questionsCorrect[i].toString(), answersCorrect[i].toString());
    dataList.add(model);
}
```

At this point, the list ready with the data and you can display in a `ListView`.

For displaying data in a `ListView`, create a custom adapter using `BaseAdapter`.

```
public class MainListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<QAnsModel> mainList;

    public MainListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<QAnsModel> mainList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mainList = mainList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mainList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mainList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView questionView;
        TextView answerView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_main_list_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.questionView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemQuestion);
            holder.answerView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemAnswer);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        QAnsModel model = (QAnsModel) getItem(position);

        holder.questionView.setText(model.getQuestion());
        holder.answerView.setText(model.getAnswer());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And create layout file item_main_list_layout.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemQuestion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemAnswer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Instead of

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataList); 
lv.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Use this:

```
MainListAdapter adapter = new MainListAdapter(this, dataList);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This should work to solve your problem.

Comment: Many thanks, this is ok. When I initialize a list view the code below return me a wrong list (eu.tecnodatasystem.multiservizi.QAnsModel@f703d7a, ......)
`final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Could you tell me whether the questions and answers in `dataList` are mapped correctly or not? And If you want to display a question and answer in a single list item, then you have to go `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to debug the application with:
`Log.d("question","Question 1: " + questionsCorrect[0]);
        Log.d("question","Answer 1: " + answersCorrect[0]);`
and they returned me the correct association.

Comment: `dataList` return me these values: `eu.tecnodatasystem.multiservizi.QAnsModel@e57f6b3, eu.tecnodatasystem.multiservizi.QAnsModel@a10c470, eu.tecnodatasystem.multiservizi.QAnsModel@39df3e9, eu.tecnodatasystem.multiservizi.QAnsModel@9c8086e, ...`